# Asymptotic calculations for Bell numbers with little-o notation

Tags: combinatorics, limits, discrete-mathematics, notation, asymptotics

I'm having trouble doing calculations with the little-o notation. Let's say that the following asymptotic formula holds for $n\to\infty$:
$$ B_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}} \exp\left( n \left(r+\frac{1}{r}-1\right)-1 \right)(1+o(1)) $$
where $r$ is the (unique and positive) solution to $re^r=n$. In the following you can assume that you can use the same $r$ for $B_n$, $B_{n+1}$ and $B_{n+2}$ (you can show that with some more asymptotics).

Somehow you can then prove the identity
$$\frac{B_{n+1}}{B_n} -1 = \frac{n}{r} (1+o(1))$$
and
$$ \frac{B_{n+2}}{B_n} - \left( \frac{B_{n+1}}{B_n} \right)^2 -1 = \frac{n}{r^2} (1+o(1)). $$
How do I go about proving these formulas?

I attempted to derive the first identity by just plugging in the asymptotic formula and got stuck:
$$ \begin{align*} \frac{B_{n+1}}{B_n} - 1 &= \frac{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}} \exp\left((n+1)\left(r+\frac{1}{r}-1\right)-1\right) (1+o(1)) }{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}} \exp\left(n\left(r+\frac{1}{r}-1\right)-1\right) (1+o(1)) } -1 \\\\
&= \exp\left(r+\frac{1}{r}-1\right)(1+o(1)) - 1 \\\\
&= e^r e^{1/r} e^{-1} (1+o(1)) -1 \\\\
&= \frac{n}{r} e^{-1} (1+o(1)) -1 .
\end{align*} $$

In the last equality I used $e^r = \frac{n}{r}$ and that $e^{1/r}=1+o(1)$ (at least I think that's true b/c $n\to\infty$ implies $r\to\infty$ and $e^{1/r}\xrightarrow{r\to\infty} 1$ and afaik that's precisely what $1+o(1)$ means for $r\to\infty$). But now there's still the term $e^{-1}$ left, of which I can't say it's $1+o(1)$, b/c $e^{-1}(1+o(1)) = e^{-1} + o(1)$. So somewhere I made a mistake but I don't know where...

(The $B_n$ are Bell numbers btw.)

Comment: As if it's not complicated enough, note you need a different $r$ in $B_{n+1}$.

Comment: You cannot use the same $r$ since $n(r_{n + 1}  - r_n ) = 1 + o(1)$.

Comment: Why is $n(r_{n+1}-r_n) = 1 +o(1)$? I was pondering too whether I could use the same $r$ in both $B_n$ and $B_{n+1}$. There's this asymptotic formula $r=\log n - \log\log n + o(1)$ (I think it comes from the W function). Since $n\to\infty$ and $r\to\infty$, I thought you could then maybe use $r_{n+1}-r_n = \log(\frac{n+1}{n}) - \log(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}) + o(1)$. This should approach $r_{n-1}-r_n = o(1)$ for large values of $n$, right? Or can I not use this reasoning in an equation involving Terms with $o$? Or does it not even make sense? (new comment b/c my old one was poorly formatted)

Comment: @Ellenier I am talking about $n(r_{n+1}-r_n)$ and not merely $r_{n+1}-r_n$. You do not necessarily have $o(n)=o(1)$.

Comment: @Ellenier Hint: by the mean value theorem $$
r_{n + 1}  - r_n  = W(n + 1) - W(n) = W'(\xi _n ) = \frac{{W(\xi _n )}}{{\xi _n (1 + W(\xi _n ))}} = \frac{1}{{\xi _n }}(1 + o(1)) = \frac{1}{n}(1 + o(1))
$$ for large $n$, where $n<\xi_n<n+1$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks for the clarification!